# A knocked-over/An overturned vending machine

Tags: word-choice, difference

> I walked past a knocked-over/an overturned vending machine.

Is one of "knocked-over" and "overturned" better than the other if I want to describe that what has happened to the vending machine has been done deliberately with force?

Comment: Was that in a novel or book? Or did you write it?

Answer (score 1):

[**Overturned** is much, much more common than **knocked-over**.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20overturned%2Ca%20knocked-over&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20overturned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20knocked%20-%20over%3B%2Cc0)  *Knocked-over* is so much less common that it calls attention to itself.  The only time I would use *knocked-over* is if it matched something else in the sentence or paragraph, like

> In their fight, Ted and Jerry had knocked over the vending machine that stood in the breakroom.  The knocked-over vending machine had spilled its contents across the floor...

But even there, *overturned* would also be perfectly natural.

Comment: I think this is rather categorical.

Comment: I completely disagree, Overturned, to me, implies a strong degree of upside-downness, whereas knocked over merely says that it is on its side. I would much more expect a vending machine to be knocked over rather than overturned.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I think that's just you.  Nothing about the dictionary definition or common usage of "overturned" necessarily means "upside-down".  For example, "[there was no struggle, else probably the dishes would have been disturbed and the chairs overturned](https://books.google.com/books?id=tPwZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA84&dq=chair+overturned+in+the&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRnOTt1OLwAhXiT98KHUQRCFY4ChDoATAIegQICBAC)".  It seems unlikely the court would think the chairs had to be upside-down.